# New to Rails and programming

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, ruby-on-rails-4, rubymine, cloud9-ide

Running rails on windows 10 (finally got it to load up), new to the programming world.
Building my 1st web app.  Should I be running rails thru an IDE (cloud 9, RubyMine) or some other virtual machine?? Any insight would be appreciated

Comment: I'm assuming by virtual machine you are talking about something like virtualbox. It's largely a matter of opinion on what tool you use, IDE vs. an editor and terminal. Depending on what tutorial, resource, or other way you try to learn will have opinions.

Comment: If you use Cloud9, you won't need to install Ruby / Rails on Windows. Cloud9 creates a Ubuntu machine for you which you can use to develop on.  (Full Disclosure: I work at Cloud9)

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm looking into cloud9 now.

Answer (score 1):

Don't develop Rails apps on Windows, you will be in for a world of hurt. (Well, to be fair, a world of having to find your way around compatibility issues, which you can probably avoid from the outset.)

Get a virtual machine provider like VirtualBox or VMWare, find a Ubuntu VM somewhere, and get it running on that instead.

For IDEs, I used to like RubyMine, but it's quite memory-hungry; these days I tend to use Sublime Text and run commands in a terminal.

Comment: Thanks a million, I have been reading up on the windows issues and all have been negative.  i'll set up a VM instead.